# C - ncurses and two concurrent threads

Tags: c, concurrency, pthreads, screen, ncurses

This program should be a trivial attempt to run two concurrent threads which both need to write on the same screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <pthread.h>
#include <ncurses.h>

void *function1(void *arg1);
void *function2(void *arg2);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("hello");

    initscr();
    printw("screen on\n");

    pthread_t function1t;
    pthread_t function2t;

    if( pthread_create( &function1t, NULL, function1, NULL) < 0)
    {
    printw("could not create thread 1");
    return 1;
    }

    if( pthread_create( &function2t, NULL, function2, NULL) < 0)
    {
    printw("could not create thread 2");
    return 1;
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;
}

void *function1(void *arg1)
{
    printw("Thread 1\n");
    while(1);
}

void *function2(void *arg2)
{
    printw("Thread 2\n");
    while(1);
}
```

But it doesn't even print `hello` in the beginning. What's wrong? How can a unique screen be handled in such a program, with two threads?

**Update**: putting a `refresh();` after each `printw` produces the following output

```
screen on



Thread 1

Thread 2

$
```

Where $ is the prompt. So, the program prints the string, but it puts (apparently) randomly some unexpected newlines and it **ends**. It shouldn’t, due to the `while(1)` instructions in both the threads!

Comment: try `refresh()` after each `printw`

Answer (score 1):

It is not printing the `hello` string but it's quickly cleared with the instruction `initscr()`:

> The initscr code determines the terminal type and initializes all
>   curses data structures. **initscr also causes the first call to refresh
>   to clear the screen**. If errors occur, initscr writes an appropriate
>   error message to standard error and exits; otherwise, a pointer is
>   returned to stdscr.

`printw` is  printing as expected because you are not refreshing. You should use `refresh()` after each `printw`:

```
printw("screen on\n");
refresh();
```

Comment: Thank you, it has been useful, but the program still seems not to work properly. I have updated my question to show its new behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

curses/ncurses in the normal configuration does not support threads, and the recommendation for *that* has always been to run curses in a single thread.  Since [ncurses 5.7](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-5.7.html), there has been rudimentary support for threaded applications if the library is configured (compile-time) to use mutexes and additional entrypoints.

Regarding mutexes, almost any tutorial on POSIX threads covers that.  Here is an example: [POSIX Threads Programming](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)

Comment: Thank you. Where can I find more documentation about mutexes?

Comment: You shouldn't be using threads if you nothing about mutexes (Mutual Exclusion Locks). That link is a good place as any to start.